# How to sort HashSet() function data in sequence?

Tags: java, sorting, hashset

I am new to Java, the function I would like to perform is to load a series of data from a file, into my hashSet() function.

the problem is, I able to enter all the data in sequence, but I can't retrieve it out in sequence base on the account name in the file.

Can anyone help?

below is my code:

public Set retrieveHistory(){
        Set dataGroup = new HashSet();
        try{

```
        File file = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\vincent\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\vincenttesting\\src\\vincenttesting\\vincenthistory.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String data = br.readLine();
        while(data != null){
            System.out.println("This is all the record:"+data);
            Customer cust = new Customer();
            //break the data based on the ,
            String array[] = data.split(",");
            cust.setCustomerName(array[0]);
            cust.setpassword(array[1]);
            cust.setlocation(array[2]);
            cust.setday(array[3]);
            cust.setmonth(array[4]);
            cust.setyear(array[5]);
            cust.setAmount(Double.parseDouble(array[6]));
            cust.settransaction(Double.parseDouble(array[7]));
            dataGroup.add(cust);
            //then proced to read next customer.

            data = br.readLine();
        } 
        br.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error" +e);
    }
    return dataGroup;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileReadDataModel fr = new FileReadDataModel();
    Set customerGroup = fr.retrieveHistory();
  System.out.println(e);
    for(Object obj : customerGroup){
        Customer cust = (Customer)obj;

        System.out.println("Cust name :" +cust.getCustomerName());
        System.out.println("Cust amount :" +cust.getAmount());

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from the [HashSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) class javadoc

> This class implements the Set
>   interface, backed by a hash table
>   (actually a HashMap instance). It
>   makes no guarantees as to the
>   iteration order of the set; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that
>   the order will remain constant over
>   time. This class permits the null 
>   element.

If you are using this class there is no way to guarantee order. You will need to introduce another data structure in order to do this. Such as [ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [LinkedHashSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).

Comment: ok i get it d... with using linkedHashSet !! thanks you so much !!

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Set is a unique (element may appear only once), non-ordered, hash-based (objects must fulfill the Object.hashCode() contract) collection.

You probably want an ordered collection. LinkedHashSet is a unique, ordered (by insertion order), hash based collection.